# Does Load Testing provides Application Server resources utilisation statistics?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, load-testing

I want to perform Load Test on Java Application using Visual studio 2012 ultimate.. I have gone through the MSDN Kb Articles however I am not sure whether the Test Results provides the Application Server and DataBase Server resources utilisation statistics... Can Anyone please let me know about it ??
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data about the performance of the servers. Open the context menu entry for **manage counter sets**, from the **Run settings** and the **Counter sets** sections of the load test. Add names (or IP addresses, but names are better as then make the final results easier to read) of the computers and select the type of server.

The **System under test** graph shown during and after the run will show some basic counters that have been collected from the servers, eg memory and CPU usage. Many other counters are collected. Expanding the tree of counters in the left hand panels shows hat has been collected and allows them to be added to a graph. New graphs can be added allowing custom graphs to be created.

It is also possible to define new sets of counters that can be collected as the test runs.

Searching the web for terms such as "visual studio load test counter sets" finds many relevant pages.

Comment: I've done all this but get nothing still under the System Under Test Resource table. I get a warning when running the load test telling me that "Load tests run using Visual Studio Team Services do not support collecting performance counters from non-agent machines. Counters will not be collected for machine [computer-name] specified in run settings."